# network load balancer en aws redirecciona incorrectamente

Tags: aws

Hola tengo un network load balancer que cuando intento navegar me esta redireccionando a una isntancia que esta fuera del target group. tengo en el listener el forwarding correctamente configurado. De repente alguna sugerencia ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: O estás accediendo a otro NLB o la instancia a la que te redirecciona sí que está en el target group. Con lso datos que expones son las dos únicas opciones que se me ocurren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL problema fue en el nginx de la instancia, estaba configurado para redireccionar todo el trafico hacia el nombre de dominio, de la instancia en producción.